# Editing Exception to send to raygun api

Tags: c#

At the moment raygun catches the errors I send using this line

```
public void SendException(Exception e)
{            
    new RaygunClient(AppConfiguration.RaygunApiKey).Send(e);
}
```

I'm looking to edit the exception so that in the message it'll give me more detail about the user and the machine along with the stacktrace. I'm wondering how do I edit the existing message or create a new message that'll also carry the stacktrace.

What I've tried is below but won't bring the stack trace over. May I ask how do I copy stack trace over.

```
public void SendException(Exception e)
{
    var exception = new Exception("Error by " + _user.FullName + " on " + Environment.UserName + " on Machine " + Environment.MachineName, e);
    new RaygunClient(AppConfiguration.RaygunApiKey).Send(exception);
}
```

I am aware that machine name is already provided within the exception.

Comment: You have use the `UserInfo` object in the raygun client object for your user id, and I'd stick the machine name in the Tag collection. Recreating an exception like this won't work. You'd have to create it, then throw it, then catch and log it and all you'll get is the stack trace of the logging code. Won't work.

Comment: @asawyer THANK YOU! that definitely was a better solution.

Comment: Your welcome! Big fan of Raygun.